# gnu parallel: print partial output on sigint

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-parallel

I use gnu parallel to run test inputs for a program in development.
Simplified setup:

```
find . -iname '*test*' | parallel -k -I@ echo running '@' \; my_binary \; echo '@': exited with \$?
```

If `my_binary` gets stuck in an infinite loop, I Ctrl+C -> SigINT this test script.

Here, unfortunately, parallel eats all the
(already printed, but buffered for ordering) stdout, so I can't see which test got stuck.

I want to get this stdout, but I did not find an option that does that in the man page. Do you have ideas on how to do this?

- I want to keep the ordering of the output (here caused by `-k`), so
  just redirecting all output directly to a file won't work (unless
  there's a trick I'm not aware of ?).
- Setting some sort of timeout for each test is impractical

  (some tests take very long, but you know there's an issue pretty
  quickly due to cpu usage etc.).
- I don't really care about using gnu-parallel, any solution would be great.

Comment: How about tagging output lines (so you can tell which process wrote them and therefore sort them) and going to line-buffered output (so you get output sooner)?

Comment: ... And then just sort by the tag and regex it away?
You're a genius! ^^. If this was an answer I would accept it :P.

Comment: I don't have details of your app/data, so see if it works for you, and write up what you did and accept your own answer and bag the points.

Comment: Oh sorry if that was confusing, I wasn't requesting free labor :), just your literal comment would have sufficed ^ ^. But all right I will try to write a decent answer in case anybody else finds this :D.

Comment: Maybe I'm lazy... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself.

parallel has a `--joblog` option that immediately prints all finished jobs, but only in order of submission!

This is exactly what we want, in combination with the tag idea from @Mark Setchell
for the following proof of concept:

```sh
output="$(mktemp)" # parallel will put the line buffered command output here
joblog="$(mktemp)" # parallel will output it's joblog here for sigint recovery

function run_test () {
   tag="$1"
   input="$2"
   echo "$tag: started $input"
   # simulate doing work for demonstration
   sleep "$tag"
   # output from the test must have the tag prepended to each line 
   echo "$input: test output"  2>&1 | sed "s/^/$tag: /" 
   echo "$tag: finished $input, exited with $?"
}

function handle_sigint () {
    echo " interrupted!"
    # check for finished jobs (tag in the joblog)
    awk '(NR>1){printf "^%s: \n", $1}' "$joblog"  | 
        # remove all output lines with tags from finished jobs
        grep -v -f - "$output" | 
        # print the remaining output lines, sorted by tag, but in order of line submission
        sort -snk1 |
        # but strip away the tag from the beginning of the line
        cut -d" " -f2-
    rm "$output"
    rm "$joblog"
    exit 0
}

export -f run_test
trap handle_sigint INT

# create some dummy jobs for demonstration
printf "foo\nbar\nbaz\nquux\n" | 
    # create command to run for each test
    awk '{printf "run_test %i %s\n", NR, $1}' | 
    # run the jobs, putting line buffered output into $output and the joblog into $joblog
    parallel --line-buffered --joblog "$joblog" bash -c  &>"$output" & 
# immedeately pipe new joblog lines along until parallel dies or we sigint
tail -f "$joblog" --pid $! |
    # whenever a job is finished --> a joblog line is added, print all lines with that tag from the output
    awk "(NR>1){c=sprintf(\"sed -n 's/^%s: //p' '%s'\\n\" , \$1, \"$output\"); system(c)}" 

# remove the temp files (if we were not interrupted, otherwise handle_sigint does this)
rm "$output" 
rm "$joblog"
```

Comment: Well done. Thank you for sharing your solution back with the community.

Answer (score 2):

How about just asking GNU Parallel which jobs are currently running:

```
seq 1000 | parallel sleep &
pid=$!
sleep 10
kill -SIGUSR1 $pid
```

Comment: It is really cool to know that this exists, thanks for that!
It would probably be possible to build a (more efficient) solution based on this e.g. by tee'ing each test stdout to a file and then printing the files of the running ones on sigint.